# ViewModel for Fragment instead accessing Activity ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, kotlin, android-architecture-components

The problem is quite straightforward. The question is in context of using ViewModels, LiveData and other related [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/package-summary.html) aware arch approaches.

I have an Activity with NavDrawer, which switches fragments inside. 
And also I have a case when two fragments are present at the same time on the screen - this will be the main pain.
One Fragment has a ViewPager with nested `Fragments`(**don't ask why**).
The other fragment is just obtaining info from first one when user performs some actions. This is achieved just by sharing activity viewmodel. But the app itself has a lot of business logic and as it goes further the viewmodel goes bigger and bigger.

 What I want to ask - not a receipt or rules how to fix this, or maybe how to overcome this by fixing the entire structure of the project. I want to ask for suggestions how can I apply the MVVM approach within android.arch.lifecycle style to mine use-case.

 I haven't seen something more complicated then just sharing the Activity ViewModel between Fragments. But common, that's not a cure.
[image]

What you can see here - a mess actually. The point is that all are sharing the `ActivityViewModel`. Connections(aggregation) from FirstFragment mean that `ViewPager` inside `FirstFragment` is initiating `ChildFragments` and they are also working with the same `ActivityViewModel`(kill me). So as result everyone is working with one shared ViewModel. 

 My proposal is to add a ViewModel for each Layer. So that Activity/Fragments/ChildFragments have their own ViewModels.
But what appears here - ***how we should communicate then***?

 Possible solutions :

- Having two ViewModels per one component. One ViewModel will handle/delegate the business logic and another will make the communication. **Two viewmodels per component - not so good, yeah?**
- Having old manner interface(**please no!**)
- Other workarounds - like DB/SharedPrefs/Realm change listeners and Event Buses(**I'm too old for this :(** ).
- **Your solution here!**

I'll say that all of the above are breaking a lot of design principles, so what should I do?
How should I come out of this mess? Is there any `Uncle Bob` or another `superhero` here to help?

**P.S.** - Well, creating UMLs or other charts isn't mine forte. Sorry for that. 

**P.P.S.** - I'm aware of [google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components) [samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture).

Comment: What's wrong with having multiple ViewModels per component? They are keyed by class name for a reason.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Hm, my thoughts on that are controversial. Always was trying to bind only one VM to one component. Lets say VM per component. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/29 - not the same, but viewmodel per screen.

Comment: when i had many viewmodels, all communication I had made through streams and changing variables in shared managers/models ex. first fragment changes input to 6 and sets it in manager (model) and manager using observable pattern (in your case it may be mutablelivedata) notify observers (other fragments observing live data variable) that value has changed

Comment: @V-master Sure, but in such case I need to have a reference to model/manager. So I'll reference two viewmodels in my fragment.

Comment: What was your conclusion?

Answer (score 18):

**What i would suggest** you can do is handle two `ViewModel` for your entire use case.

Make one `ViewModel`

Let's say **`MyActivityViewModel`** to handle all logic related for **activity** level. So, if any **fragment** logic is directly related to your **activity** then share your `ViewModel` like below :

```
ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyActivityViewModel.class); // Like this in fragment.
```

&

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyActivityViewModel.class); // Like this in activity.
```

*This will share common `ViewModel` between your **activity** and **fragment***.

---

Another `ViewModel` would go for `FirstFragment` in your case if you have to share logic between your `ChildFragment` :

Here you can share `ViewModel` let's say `FragmentViewModel` like below:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FragmentViewModel.class); // Like this in FirstFragment which is having view pager.
```

&

```
ViewModelProviders.of(getParentFragment()).get(FragmentViewModel.class); // Like this in View pager fragments, getParentFragment() is First fragment in our case.
```

Although, we can still use our activity level **`MyActivityViewModel`** in our child fragments from FirstFragment like :

```
ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyActivityViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 7):

First there is no harm in having *multiple* `ViewModel`'s for a *single* **View**.

I would think about my **ViewModel**'s like what kind of *data* is getting and manipulating, and group them in a way, that seems natural.

For your case, if the fragments and the activity's logic is very similar, I think you can go with a single `ViewModel`, but I would avoid that.

What I would do is break the activity's `ViewModel` into smaller parts and reuse the proper `ViewModel`'s in my `Fragments`, so that I wouldn't have a **God ViewModel**, nor roughly the same code in different **ViewModel**'s.

Answer (score 5):

This is updated version of answer given by Jeel Vankhede. And also Kotlin implementation of the same.

Since ViewModelProviders is deprecated now we have to use ViewModelProvider.

Here is how you do it in Activity:

```
ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

Here is how you do  in Fragment:

```
ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: This is the answer that we're all looking for: simple, works.  [applause]

Comment: I am in trouble. This is the code: mainCommandModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MainCommandModel.class);
        mainCommandModel.getActiveState().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), mainCommandObserver);

This causes a second call to the mainCommandModel (the viewmodel) constructor, and therefore, the fragment having this code never observe the changes done by activity, probably because activity also called that cnstructor. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem of `FirstFragment` sharing its view model with its child fragments, you can use this code to access the `FirstFragmentViewModel` from any of the child fragments:

```
    // in ChildFragment1
    val firstFragmentViewModel: FirstFragmentViewModel by viewModels(
        { requireParentFragment() }
    )
```