# Get parent fragment from child when using Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I need to transfer data from one fragment to another. Now the recommended way to do this is to use a shared `ViewModel`. To get the same instance available in both fragments, common owner is needed. As it can be their common `Activity`. But with this approach (In the case of Single Activity), the `ViewModel` instance will live throughout the entire application. In the classic use of fragments, you can specify `ViewModelProvider (this)` in the parent fragment, and `ViewModelProvider (getParentFramgent ())` in the child. Thus, the scope of `ViewModel` is limited to the life of the parent fragment. The problem is that when using Navigation Component, `getParentFramgent ()` will return NavHostFragment, not the parent fragment. What do I need to do?

**Code samples**:

Somewhere in navigation_graph.xml:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav"
        app:startDestination="@id/mainMenuFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuFragment"
        android:name="com.mypackage.mainmenu.MainMenuFragment"
        android:label="MainMenu"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_menu">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/start_game_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/gameNav" />

    </fragment>

    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/gameNav"
        app:startDestination="@id/gameFragment">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/gameFragment"
            android:name="com.mypackage.game.GameFragment"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game"/>
    </navigation>

</navigation>
```

Somewhere in `MainMenuFragment`:

```
    override fun startGame(gameSession: GameSession) {
            //This approach doesn't work
            ViewModelProvider(this)[GameSessionViewModel::class.java].setGameSession(
                gameSession
            )
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.start_game_fragment)
    }
```

`GameFragment`:

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
            gameSessionViewModel =
                ViewModelProvider(requireParentFragment())[GameSessionViewModel::class.java].apply {
                    val session = gameSession.value
                    )
                }
    }
```

EDIT:

I can use `NavHostFragment`(returned from `getParentFragment()`) as a common for all fragments, but then, as in the case of `Activity`, `ViewModel.onCleared()` will not be called when the real parent fragment finishes.

Comment: can you post the code for adding the child fragment

Comment: @FahadAlotaibi, simply findNavController().navigate(R.id.start_game_fragment)

Comment: so, NavHostFragment will be the parent fragment and all the fragments will be added as child fragment

Comment: @FahadAlotaibi, yes, this NavHostFragment is common to all fragments. It is instantiated in activity. It will live while activity is alive.

Comment: @FahadAlotaibi, For example, if I use the approach one Fragment, one ViewModel, when the fragment ends, the ViewModel will call onCleared ()

Comment: @Ziens also have a look at my questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70721218/receive-fragment-result-in-navigation-component-fragment and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70680327/toolbar-icon-handling-using-navigation-component

Answer (score 4):

There's really no way to do this.

Here is a code snippet from `androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator`:

```
public NavDestination navigate(@NonNull Destination destination, @Nullable Bundle args,
                    @Nullable NavOptions navOptions, @Nullable Navigator.Extras navigatorExtras) {
    // ...
    final FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    // ...
    ft.replace(mContainerId, frag);
    ft.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(frag);
    // ...
}
```

Under the hood, the `FragmentManager` is used, which calls `replace()`. Therefore, the child fragment is not added, but is replaced with a new one, so it will not be in `getParentFramgent()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this piece of code to access **parent fragment** functions using **navigation component**:

**First Method**

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getParentFragment();
ParentFragment parent = (ParentFragment) navHostFragment.getParentFragment();
parent.somePublicFunctin();
```

**Second Method**

```
ParentFragment parent =((ParentFragment)CurrentFragmentName.this.getParentFragment());
parent.somePublicFunctin();
```

Comment: do make sure before casting that the parent fragment is the instance of given parent fragment class

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and after researching and experimenting, I found the solution.

You simply have to call this while scoping your ViewModel which will resolve to your fragment where you have created the navigation host fragment.

```
ViewModelProvider(getParentFragment().getParentFragment())
```

or more appropriately

```
ViewModelProvider(requireParentFragment().requireParentFragment())
```

(to avoid NPE)

This is because child fragment's parent is NavHostFragment and NavHostFragment's parent is ParentFragment.

I tested this and it's working fine for me

Comment: this did not work for me :( the parent's parent was null for me..

Answer (score 1):

for those of you who are bothered with this problem, here is the answer that worked for me:

suppose that you go from fragment A to fragment B, and you want to use a shared ViewModel for fragment A and B, and in this case, A is a fragment and B is a dialogFragment.

you can initialize ViewModel in fragment A:

```kotlin
ViewModelProvider(this).get(AviewModel::class.java)
```

and in order to use it on fragment B, initialize the ViewModel in fragment B like this:

```kotlin
ViewModelProvider(requireParentFragment().childFragmentManager.fragments[0]).get(AviewModel::class.java)
```

TL;DR:

`requireParentFragment()` returns `NavHostFragment` which hosts all the navigation of the current navigation.

`requireParentFragment().childFragmentManager` returns `FragmentManagerImpl` which seems to be the container for all fragments.

`requireParentFragment().childFragmentManager.fragments` returns a mutable list of fragments that are in the stack, so you can iterate through the list to see the fragments that are living in stack.